# SSIS MDX Query Problem

Tags: ssis, filter, ssas, mdx

Hallo at all!

I have a little Problem with my Query in MDX.

I try to query up the Damage Repair Types from my Cube. Next i explain my Dimension and the Fact Table:

Dimension: Demage Repair Type

RepairTypeKey  |  Name  |  RepairTypeAlternateKey  |  RepairSubTypeAlternateKey  | SubName 
 0 |Unknown |0 | *NULL* | *NULL* 
1 |Repair |1 |1 | 1 Boil 
2 |Replacement |2 |*NULL* | *NULL* 
3 |Repair |1 |2 | 2 Boils 
4 |Repair |1 |3 | 3 Boils

So I have in my Fact Table "CLaimCosts" for every Claim one RepairTypeKey. I Fill the Tables and design a Cube. The Dimension have a Hirarchy with RepairType and SubRepairType. I Process the Cube and it works Fine:

- Demage Repair Type

  - Hirarchy

    - Members

      - All

        - Replacement
        - Repair

          - 1 Boil
          - 2 Boils
          - 3 Boils
        - Unknown

Now I Create a Query with MDX:

```
select
    {
        [Measures].[Claim Count],
        [Measures].[Claim Cost Position Count],
        [Measures].[Claim Cost Original],
        [Measures].[Claim Cost Original Average],
        [Measures].[Claim Cost Possible Savings],
        [Measures].[Claim Cost Possible Savings Average],
        [Measures].[Claim Cost Possible Savings Percentage] 
    } on 0,

    NON EMPTY{
        NonEmpty([Damage Repair Type].[Hierarchy].Allmembers, ([Measures].[Claim Count]))
    } on 1

    from 
        Cube

    where 
    (
        ({StrToMember(@DateFrom) : StrToMember(@DateTo)})
        ,([Claim Document Type].[Document Type].&[4])


    )
```

Now i try to Run the Query and it Works but i have to much Rows Shown:

Demage Repair Type | Demage Repair Sub Type | Claim Count | .... 
*NULL* |*NULL* | 200000 
Replacement | *NULL* | 150000 
Repair | *NULL* | 45000 
Repair | 1 Boil | 10000 
Repair | 2 Boil | 15000 
Repair | 3 Boil | 19000 
Unknown |*NULL* | 1000

My Problem are the frist Row (Sum) and the third Row (Sum)! I don't need this Rows but I don't know how to Filter them! I don't need this Sums because i have the Childs with the right Counts!

How I can Filter this? Please help me. It doesn't work!

Sorry for my bad English and Thank you!

Alex

Comment: Nobody a Idea? If you have Question, you can ask! Then i can try to explain better.

Comment: what is the logic for removing rows (why not second and last) ? --- check the filter() and isEmpty() functions.

Comment: There are not as many people in MDX as for other subjects, you've to be a bit more pacient to get a 'free' answer ;-)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NonEmpty([Damage Repair Type].[Hierarchy].Allmembers, ([Measures].[Claim Count]))
```

You can use:

```
NonEmpty([Damage Repair Type].[Hierarchy].Levels(2).Members, [Measures].[Claim Count])
```

This way we exclude the All members. Also, when you use the level members (e.g. [dim].[hier].[lvl].Members) instead of the hierarchy members (e.g. [dim].[hier].members) you don't get the aggregate members - e.g. the All member which is commonly present in all hierarchies other than non-aggregatable attribute hierarchies.

Comment: Thanks! It works! :) The only one Problem, that I can't fix: If I show the Data trough a Tablix it show the Data right! If i Build a total at the end of the tablix, it Sum the whole Sum! It Sum the Parent Hirarchy "Repair" and the Child-Hirarchy "1 Boil, 2 Boils etc." But it is the Same Value.

Comment: Just remove the DRT.H.Levels(1).Members from the set - then it should work as you want it...